# iPhone - Button getting dissappeard 

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, hidden

I am having a table view . On a cell I am adding a button ( UIButton customButton ). But sometimes that button disappears. I checked the whole code , nowhere I am modifying the button properties. I have also retained the button . 
        Actually button is still there but not visible. If I click on buttons location the call back function on button gets called. I don't know what's going wrong. I have checking this from 2 days but didn't find any bug. I am pasting below the code for that. If anyone has faced this issue , please help me !!!

```
    logOutBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [logOutBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUE.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logOutBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 2, 100, 35)];
    [logOutBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(SignOut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [logOutBtn retain];
```

Adding the complete code.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     // Return the number of sections.
     return 3;
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.

switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        return 4;
        break;

    case 2:
        return 1;
        break;

}

return 0;
```

}

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    return 90;
}   
    return 50;
 }
```

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
int newCellFlag = 0;
UITableViewCell *cell;
UILabel * titleLabel;
UIImageView * logoView;
UIButton * infoBtn;

// Configure the cell...
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        //add the custom button for cities
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
            newCellFlag = 1;
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }


     if (newCellFlag == 1)
             {

                if (indexPath.row==0) {

                    /*cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"My city subscriptions";*/
                    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                    logoView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
                    logoView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 295, 80);
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:logoView];
                    [logoView release];

                    infoBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
                    infoBtn.frame = CGRectMake(270, 75, 15, 15);
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:infoBtn];
                    [infoBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(infoView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


                }
                if (indexPath.row ==1) {
                        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
                        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Add cities";
                        //[cell.contentView addSubview:_AddCitiesButton];
                    }
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
            newCellFlag = 1 ;
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

        //add the custom button for cities
        if (newCellFlag == 1)
        {
                if (indexPath.row ==0) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"User name";
                        cell.detailTextLabel.text =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user_name"];   
                        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                        }
                if (indexPath.row ==1) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Credits left";
                        cell.detailTextLabel.text = (connected ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",[self getUserMoney]] : @"Not Available.");
                        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                        //[cell.contentView addSubview:_creditsLabel];
                        }

                if (indexPath.row ==2) {
                        cell.textLabel.text = @"Current City";
                        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"current_city_name"];
                        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                        //[cell.contentView addSubview:_currentCity];
                        }
                if (indexPath.row == 3) {
                        /*
                        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 100, 35)];
                        titleLabel.text = @"Log out";
                        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
                        titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:15.5];
                        titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.5];
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
                        [titleLabel release];
                         */
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:logOutBtn];
                        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                        }
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        //add the custom button for cities
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            newCellFlag = 1;
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        if (newCellFlag ==1 ) {
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"App Version";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"1.0";
                    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                    }

        break;
    default:
        break;
}


 if(newCellFlag == 1)
 {


if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    CommonBG * bg = [[CommonBG alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    cell.backgroundView = bg;
    cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;//[UIColor clearColor];
    [bg release];

}
else {
CommonBG * bg = [[CommonBG alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
cell.backgroundView = bg;
[bg release];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
}
}       
    return cell;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the cell creation ? UITableView use a deque to reuse cells which are not displayed maybe the core of your problem is here

Comment: show code of all methods of tableview.

Comment: @RakeshBhatt , I have edited the question to add the complete code .

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is there but you can't see it, and method associated with it being called(SignOut). so put this line

[logOutBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

if your button shows with red rectangular shape then there is a problem in image either you are not giving name correct or any problem in that image. check spelling of BLUE.png .

also it is case sensitive so check this also. and spelling is not matter then try to use other image.

Comment: @Ishu: No I checked it actually button is not there . . .

Comment: Nice debugging method, but it doesn't actually prove anything apart from the fact that the button is there, which we already know because it responds to touch.
The fact that it sometimes _does_ appear proves that there is nothing wrong with the spelling. That leaves something being seriously wrong with the button or the image being released too early. Of the two, the latter is more likely.
If you don't know exactly what you're talking about, or haven't had the experience yourself, please don't post answers which don't actually help in the long run.

Comment: If button is not there then how can you click on that.

Comment: Exactly. If you can click, it means the button is there. The only thing setting the colour to red proves is that the button is there, but we already know the button is there so making it red is completely pointless.

Comment: Sorry guys Actually button is not there . I checked the code , mistakenly I was calling same function (of the button ) on cell selection. SO I thot it is there . But I removed that code . The button is not there .

Comment: @NightLeopard, it is just for confirm that button is there and no other view comes over that partially, suppose i am making an custom button and make a label in a cell then by default label color is white.and wrongly label overlaps button partally or completely then setting color always helps in these cases.so dont think this is pointless.also if your spelling is not follow case then it shows in simulator but not in device.so don't think these hints are pointless.

Comment: @Bharat J, check other view is not overlapping the button frame.by setting different background  color to different controls.

Comment: I found out the cause . It was a threading issue . I still don't understand it but let me explain.

I was creating a thread in viewWillAppear: Method . This thread would fetch data from server and would reload the cell just above the button cell . I don't quite agree with this but may be reloading som table cells from secondary thread might be causing it. Not quite sure. But when I removed the thread , it worked out and button is visible now.

Answer (score 0):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` aka `+ (UIImage)imageNamed:(NSString *)name` is a convenience method returns an autoreleased item, which means that the image can be released before it makes it to the button.

Try using `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUE.png"] retain]` or `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"BLUE.png"]`.

Comment: I don't think this can be the cause as UIButton will be retaining the UIImage objec. I tried it , it's not working ...

Comment: UIButton has setImage method that retains the UIImage.  So it is perfectly fine to use [UIImage imageNamed] when passing it to setImage.

Comment: I have had problems with this before, in the exact same situation, and that's exactly how I fixed it. And anyway, I can't really see another explanation as to why the button would disappear.
EDIT: The button is also autoreleased. That could be the problem.

Comment: I found out the cause . It was a threading issue . I still don't understand it but let me explain.

I was creating a thread in viewWillAppear: Method . This thread would fetch data from server and would reload the cell just above the button cell . I don't quite agree with this but may be reloading som table cells from secondary thread might be causing it. Not quite sure. But when I removed the thread , it worked out and button is visible now.

Comment: @BharatJ Creating threads in an iPhone app when you don't have a definite understanding of how they work is **not** a good idea.

Comment: @NightLeopard , I didn't exactly get you !!

Comment: @BharatJ if you aren't completely sure about how a thread works, do some research before using one, so you don't get strange results.